# Identify Component under mouse cursor does not work with TImage Control

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

I am using the following Procedure to identify the controls under my mouse in Delphi XE3.  All works well for `vcl.contols`. However when the mouse is over a `TImage`, no control name is returned.

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: oolean);    
var
  ctrl : TWinControl;
begin    
  ctrl := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos);     
  if ctrl <> nil then begin    
    Label2.caption := ctrl.Name;    
    //do something if mouse is over TLabeledEdit    
    if ctrl is TLabeledEdit the begin    
      Caption := TLabeledEdit(ctrl).Text;    
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a simple way to access the names of a `TImage` - am I missing something really simple?

Comment: I have looked for an example using - FindDragTarget(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean): TControl

Comment: I have looked for an example using - 

FindDragTarget(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean): TControl 

But have not been able to find one :(

Can anybody point me in the right direction or provide example including any objects / items that must be added to the 'uses' section?

Comment: My friendly advice is to stop being a "copy-paste-programmer". Learn by reading docs and thinking yourself. You have been told why `FindVCLWindow()` doesn't work for you and what function to use instead. You also know what the function returns, change the `ctrl` variable to that type. Look in help, what the additional `AllowDisabled` parameter means if you can't guess it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FindVCLWindow` finds descendants of `TWinControl`. Since `TImage` is not windowed control and it does not inherit from `TWinControl`, `FindVCLWindow` will not be able to find it. Just like it will not be able to find any other control that does not have `TWinControl` class among its ancestors.

However, there is similar function `FindDragTarget` that will return any VCL control, including non-window ones.

This function is also declared in `Vcl.Controls`, just like `FindVCLWindow`

```
function FindDragTarget(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean): TControl;
```

It has extra argument - `AllowDisabled` which controls whether it will return disabled controls or not.

You should rewrite your method as following - note that `ctrl` must be redeclared as `TControl`

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
var
  ctrl : TControl;
begin
  ctrl := FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, true);
  if ctrl <> nil then
    begin
      Label2.caption := ctrl.Name;
      ...
    end;
end;
```